# Why do I get "incompatible pointer type" when assigning pointers to a multidimensional array

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm trying to have a matrix of nodes to save an int value that changes through every iteration based on its neighbours, so I decided that I should have a "Node" struct that saves its value and the list of Nodes that are near, but when compiling I get the following warning when assigning a Node to the list:

> warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types] n -> neighbours[0] = table[M - 1][N - 1];

That warning causes that my nodes won't initialize causing a segmentation error when I'm trying to access to any variable inside my structure (I think because its NULL).

Here is my code, hope you can help me with this

```c
...
typedef struct node {
    int state;
    struct Node** neighbours;
} Node;

Node* node_init(int i, int j, int M, int N, Node*** table) {
    Node* n = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    n -> state = -1;
    n -> neighbours = malloc(sizeof(Node*)*8);
    if (i == 0 && j == 0) {  // (0, 0)
        n -> neighbours[0] = table[M - 1][N - 1];  // Here is the problem
        n -> neighbours[1] = table[M - 1][j];
        n -> neighbours[2] = table[M - 1][j + 1];
        n -> neighbours[3] = table[i][N - 1];
        n -> neighbours[4] = table[i][j + 1];
        n -> neighbours[5] = table[i + 1][N - 1];
        n -> neighbours[6] = table[i + 1][j];
        n -> neighbours[7] = table[i + 1][j + 1];
    } ...  // for all cases
    return n;

Node*** table = malloc(sizeof(Node**)*M);          // M is the amount of rows
for (int i=0; i < M; i++) {
    Node** nodes = malloc(sizeof(Node*)*N);        // N is the amount of cols
    table[i] = nodes;
    for (int j=0; j < N; j++) {
        Node* node = node_init(i, j, M, N, table); // wont reach here
        table[i][j] = node;
        fscanf(fp, "%i", &(node -> state));        // ain't relevant

    }
}
...
```

I know that the first time I do

```
n -> neighbours[0] = table[M - 1][N - 1]
```

I'm assigning a random value that is pointed by that position of table, but I don't think that's a problem, right?

Anyways, hope you can help me

Thank you :)

Comment: This question, as it was originally asked, has been answered. Please don't edit it into an entirely different thing. Instead, post a new question and leave this one alone.

Comment: ^ or try debugging the program before posting a new question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`table[M - 1][N - 1]` is a `Node*`, which after `typedef struct node { /* ... */ } Node;` is applied, is a `struct node*`. `n -> neighbours[0]` is a `struct Node*`. Since C is case-sensitive, those are really pointers to two completely different structs.

Comment: Yeah! Just noticed that, thank you, cant believe it hahaha. However, I'm still gotting that segmentation error :(